# java applet logging 7u13

Tags: java, logging, applet

I've just installed the new JDK7u13, but the logging applet doesn't work. I can't see any log messages in console. The applet worked fine in 7u11. I've tried with a simple program (not applet) and it works. Of course, I've recompiled the applet, revised logging.properties. Is there a new parameter I must configure in new JRE update?

An example:

### Hello.class:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.util.logging.*;

public class Hello extends Applet {

      private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger("Hello");

   @Override
   public void init() {
      log.info("Hello!!");
      System.out.println("mmmhhhh....");
   }
   // TODO overwrite start(), stop() and destroy() methods
}
```

### Console:

```
Java Plugin 10.13.2.20
Usando versión de JRE 1.7.0_13-b20 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
Directorio raíz del usuario = C:\Documents and Settings\commander
----------------------------------------------------
c:   borrar ventana de consola
f:   finalizar objetos en la cola de finalización
g:   recopilación de basura
h:   mostrar este mensaje de ayuda
l:   volcar lista de classloader
m:   imprimir uso de memoria
o:   disparar registro
q:   ocultar consola
r:   recargar configuración de política
s:   volcar propiedades del sistema y de despliegue
t:   volcar lista de threads
v:   volcar pila de threads
x:   borrar caché de classloader
0-5: definir nivel de rastreo en <n>
----------------------------------------------------
mmmhhhh....
```

Where is the info message "Hello!!"?

In JRE1.6 (for instance), the same applet produce:

```
Java Plug-in 1.6.0_07
Usar versión JRE 1.6.0_07 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
Directorio local del usuario = C:\Documents and Settings\commander
----------------------------------------------------
c:   borrar ventana de consola
f:   finalizar objetos en la cola de finalización
g:   liberación de recursos
h:   presentar este mensaje de ayuda
l:   volcar lista del cargador de clases
m:   imprimir sintaxis de memoria
o:   activar registro
p:   recargar configuración de proxy
q:   ocultar consola
r:   recargar configuración de norma
s:   volcar propiedades del sistema y de despliegue
t:   volcar lista de subprocesos
v:   volcar pila de subprocesos
x:   borrar antememoria del cargador de clases
0-5: establecer nivel de rastreo en <n>
----------------------------------------------------
05-feb-2013 11:18:50 Hello init
INFO: Hello!!
mmmhhhh....
```

Thank you.

Comment: How very odd.  Calling for a 'named logger' in an applet used to cause an `AccessControlExeption`.  Now, neither the static final named logger, nor a non-static, non-final anonymous logger shows anything in the console.  Maybe logging was redirected in 7?

Comment: Thanks Andrew. This applet will run like a private application downloaded from local computer. I gave it all permisions in java.policy.

Comment: *"This applet will run like a private application downloaded from local computer"*  That is not a good case for deploying an applet.  Give the user an executable Jar instead.  I would not be surprised if that solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks again Andrew. You're right: a jar works!!! I mentioned it before, but it doesn't work in an applet with jdk1.7.0_13. Why??? Any idea???

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.util.logging.*;

public class Hello extends Applet {

      private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger("Hello");

   @Override
   public void init() {
      log.addHandler(new ConsoleHandler()); // ADD THIS LINE TO YOUR CODE
      log.info("Hello!!");
      System.out.println("mmmhhhh....");
   }
   // TODO overwrite start(), stop() and destroy() methods
}
```

For any reason the LogManager isn't reading the *handlers* value of properties file so to solve your problem you only need to add the handler programmatic as I show in the code above. I will try to debug a little more.

Comment: Carlos, thank you very much. Now it's working. I think plugin is not reading logging.propierties file: if you change level to SEVERE at file, the applet shows Hello!! message. I've changed runtime parameters in panel console (-Djavaplugin.log.filename="C:\Archivos de programa\Java\jre7\lib\logging.properties") but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I used your applet code with jdk1.7.0_09 with this logging.properties:

```
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

and I got this output in console:

Feb 05, 2013 12:08:35 PM Hello init
INFO: Hello!!
mmmhhhh....

Comment: Thanks Carlos. My jre/lib/logging.propierties file has got the same lines. The applet works fine until jdk1.7.0_11, but not in jdk1.7_0_13 (????)